# Wrap string keys to make distinction between external and internal keys

Tags: java, java-8

We have two kinds of IDs, internal and externalA. Currently records have both internal and externalA IDs, and in future there might be externalB types of IDs so some records could have internal and externalB IDs.

We currently represent all IDs as Strings. It can lead to bugs, where a method expects internal, but externalA key was actually passed.

How do we prevent this type of error? Would wrapping String keys into InternalID, ExternalAID, ExternalBID classes and use those wrappers everywhere work for us?
I am concerned about memory footprint, which could especially happen if we are talking about hundreds of millions of keys, and maybe other stuff that can go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a discriminator for all of the string keys.  for example:

```
String internalKey= "I1000201";
String externalAKey= "A1000201";
String externalBKey= "B1000201";
```

Then you can prevent the error by checking the actual key type by the first char, for example:

```
char type =  key.charAt(0);
if(type != 'I') throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key");
// go on
```

You also can create your own `Key` class from `String` keys if all of the keys take a distinct discriminator.

```
Key internal = Key.from("I1000201"); //internal key
Key external = Key.from("A1000201"); //external key A
Key.from("X1000201"); 
//        ^--- throws IllegalArgumentException for invalid key type
```

---

```
public class Key {
    private final String key;
    private final Visibility visibility;

    private static final BitSet externals = new BitSet();

    static {
        // register your own external key here
        externals.set('A');
        externals.set('B');
    }

    //      v--- make the Key constructor private.
    private Key(String key, Visibility visibility) {
        this.key = key;
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }


    public static Key from(String key) {
        return new Key(key, visibilityOf(key));
    }

    private static Visibility visibilityOf(String key) {
        char type = key.charAt(0);
        return type == 'I' ? Visibility.INTERNAL
                           : externals.get(type) ? Visibility.EXTERNAL
                                                 : failsOnInvalidKey(key);
    }

    private static Visibility failsOnInvalidKey(String key) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Key: \"" + key + "\"");
    }

    public char type() {
        return key.charAt(0);
    }

    public String value() {
        return key.substring(1);
    }

    public boolean isExternal() {
        return visibility == Visibility.EXTERNAL;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return key;
    }

    // preserve it maybe will introduce additional behavior in future
    private enum Visibility {
        EXTERNAL,
        INTERNAL
    }
}
```

Comment: that was my thought exactly

Comment: @Eugene I'm also inspired by one table support for all entities in hibernate. :)

Comment: we do that internally in our code base too if I remember correctly, where we carry a `byte[]` and the first `byte` is always just some metadata..